# Es wäre mir ein Anliegen, den Fall alleine (zu?) lösen (zu?) versuchen

Tags: grammar, infinitive

Nach fünfzigmaliger Wiederholung aller möglichen Varianten des Satzes

> Es wäre mir ein Anliegen, den Fall alleine zu lösen versuchen. *(?)*

weiß ich nicht mehr, was richtig und was falsch. Um ehrlich zu sein, wusste ich das vorher wahrscheinlich auch nicht.

Eine mögliche Umgehung wäre

> Es wäre mir ein Anliegen, zu versuchen, den Fall alleine zu lösen.

Aber wie sieht es nun aus, wenn ich die zwei Infinitive hintereinander haben möchte? Wie viele *zu*s brauche ich und wie müssen sie angeordnet sein (wenn überhaupt möglich)?

Comment: Duden sagt, du sollst es lassen ;) : "...das Nebeneinander von mehreren Infinitiven mit *zu*, die voneinander abhängen, führt schnell zu komplexen Konstruktionen [sic] und sollte aus stilistischen Gründen wie aus Grünnden der Deutlichkeit vermieden werden..."

Comment: @tofro Gibt's da evtl. einen Link dazu oder ist das aus einem Buch?

Comment: Leider kein Link: *Duden: Richtiges und gutes Deutsch", 7. Auflage 2014, S. 493

Comment: @tofro Auf die Gefahr hin, mich unbeliebt zu machen - auch hier finde ich wieder einmal, dass es sich der Duden zu einfach macht. Grundsätzlich stimme ich zu, dass man unnötig lange Infinitivfolgen vermeiden sollte. Das Argument der Deutlichkeit ist allerdings leicht entkräftet: Das Deutsche ist eine der wenigen Sprachen, bei dem vieles durch Reihenfolge eindeutig wird. Ich denke, man sollte sich immer die Alternativen ansehen. Und bei zwei Infinitiven ist die Reihung am Ende meiner Meinung nach deutlich eleganter als der Einschub mitten im Satz und damit auch stilistisch zu bevorzugen.

Comment: vielleicht ist "zu einfach machen" auch falsch ausgedrückt. Man muss eben irgendwo eine Grenze der Komplexität ziehen, denn sonst würden die Regeln des Duden-Bandes "Richtiges und gutes Deutsch" nicht nur ein Buch, sondern ein ganzes Regal füllen ;)

Comment: @yggdrasil Gerade bei diesem Beispiel wird an sich deutlich, dass die *Reihenfolge*, die du anführst, für die Bedeutung vollkommen irrelevant ist. Wenn man die zwei Infinitive vertauscht, bleibt die eigentliche Bedeutung exakt dieselbe. Falls mein Kommentar den Eindruck "der Duden hat immer recht" erweckt hat: Nein, das ist nicht generell meine Meinung, hier aber schon. Sätze wie diesen, bei denen man zweimal Luft holen muss, finde ich stilistisch ausgesprochen unschön und auch beim Lesen "stolpert" mein Lesefluss bei sowas. Das ist möglicherweise allerdings größtenteils Geschmackssache.

Comment: @tofro: Stimmt, in diesem Fall ist die Reihenfolge tatsächlich egal. Das allerdings bestärkt nur meine Aussage, dass die Verwendung keinen Einfluss auf die Eindeutigkeit hat.
Ein Beispiel, wo es tatsächlich auf die Reihenfolge ankommt: "Ich habe versucht, dich zu überreden zu gehen" ist ein sinnvoller Satz, "Ich habe versucht, dich zu gehen zu überreden" hingegen nicht. Ich werde an dieser Stelle später noch ein Beispiel mit unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen posten, wenn mir eins einfällt. Neulich hatte ich tatsächlich ein solches und genau diese Diskussion schon mit einem Kollegen.

Comment: Was den Stil angeht, würde ich hier zwischen der gesprochenen und der geschriebenen Sprache unterscheiden. In der gesprochenen Sprache würde ich wohl tatsächlich auch den eingeschobenen Infinitiv verwenden, in der geschriebenen Sprache bevorzuge ich die "direkte" Variante.

Comment: Der Kommentar machte nicht direkt den Eindruck, dass du alles aus dem Duden unhinterfragt unterschreibst, nur leider wird das hier oft als Totschlagargument verwendet, das keinen weiteren Widerspruch mehr duldet. Dabei wird häufig vergessen, dass es sich bei dem Autoren-Team des Dudens auch nur um Menschen handelt (wenn auch sehr kompetente), und dass teilweise nur mit der Mehrheit einer Stimme entschieden wird, was wie in den Büchern veröffentlicht wird und sich teilweise schon durch den Austausch eines Team-Mitglieds ändert. Das als einzig mögliche Wahrheit zu sehen, halte ich für falsch.

Answer (score 3):

Die Konstruktion mit „Es wäre mir ein Anliegen …“ hört sich ganz schön gestelzt an. Wenn es unbedingt so sein muss, würde ich (als Muttersprachler) intuitiv – und mit Magendrücken – sagen

- Es wäre mir ein Anliegen, den Fall alleine zu lösen zu versuchen. oder
- Es wäre mir ein Anliegen zu versuchen, den Fall alleine zu lösen.

(Ob es korrekt ist, in der zweiten Version das erste Komma wegzulassen, weiß ich nicht – habe ich aus dem Gefühl heraus so gemacht, denn die erste Pause zum Luftholen würde ich nicht zwischen „Anliegen“ und „zu versuchen“ machen, sondern erst vor „den Fall“. Tofro hat angemerkt (vielen Dank!), dass das lt. Duden wohl auch akzeptabel ist, sein Gefühl aber eher noch ein Komma vor das „zu versuchen“ verlangen würde. Also Geschmacksache bzw. eine Frage der Betonung und Gruppierung …)

Viel flüssiger wäre jedoch eine Formulierung in der Art von

- Ich möchte gerne versuchen, den Fall alleine zu lösen.
- Ich würde den Fall lieber alleine lösen.
- Ich würde lieber versuchen, den Fall alleine zu lösen.
- Mein Anliegen ist zu versuchen, den Fall alleine zu lösen.
- Es ist mir wichtig, den Fall alleine zu lösen.
- Es ist mir wichtig zu versuchen, den Fall alleine zu lösen.

usw.

Comment: Ich finde die Alternativen gut, allerdings würde ich "Mein Anliegen ist zu versuchen, den Fall alleine zu lösen." nicht als flüssig bezeichnen. Den Satz würde ich so niemals sagen.

Comment: Da stimme ich dir völlig zu :-) Das habe ich nur als Alternative gegeben, die das "...mein Anliegen ist..." in halbwegs gut verdaulicher Form mit verarbeitet. In freier Wildbahn würde ich das auch weder schreiben, noch aussprechen.

Comment: Man versucht etwas zu tun, daher würde ich diese zwei Worte in deinem ersten Punkt vertauchen: "Es wäre mir ein Anliegen, den Fall alleine zu versuchen zu lösen." Wesentlich besser fände ich: "Es wäre mir ein Anliegen, den Fall versuchen alleine zu lösen." Oder: "... den Fall alleine versuchen zu lösen."

Comment: @Mackie, ich glaube "Es wäre mir ein Anliegen, den Fall versuchen alleine zu lösen" ist falsch.

Comment: Es kommt darauf an, worauf sich das "alleine" bezieht. Man kann etwas alleine versuchen und man kann etwas alleine lösen (also auch etwas versuchen alleine zu lösen). Ich denke daher, beides ist möglich. Oder hast du eine Quelle?

Comment: @Mackie, du hast zwei Infinitve und beide benötigen ein "zu": "Mein Anliegen ist etw. zu tun" und "versuchen etw. zu tun", also brauchst du in der Kombination beider Infinitive auch zwei "zu".

Comment: Ah, ich dachte, du meinst die Stellung des "alleine". Was das "zu" vor "versuchen" betrifft: Für mich klingt es ohne einfach richtig. Aber ich finde weder Regel noch Ausnahme, also hast du vermutlich Recht.

Comment: Danke :) Umschreibungen fallen mir genügend viele ein, aber mir geht's ja nicht darum, eine leichte/gängigere Alternative zu finden, sondern darum, auch mit dieser Konstruktion informiert umgehen zu können.

Comment: ...nicht alles, was möglich und korrekt ist, ist sinnvoll... Mit manchen Möglichkeiten sollte man besser gar nicht umgehen, im Interesse des Gemeinwohls (bzw. der Verständlichkeit). genau wie tofro ganz oben den Duden zitiert hat. (Nur meine persönliche Meinung...)

Comment: (man kann/darf) > (man soll nicht/darf nicht)

Answer (score 3):

Wenn du unbedingt die Konstruktion mit den beiden Infinitiven wählen willst, (siehe Empfehlung im Kommentar oben) gelten meiner Ansicht nach folgende Regeln:

Duden unterscheidet zwischen dem "zu"-Infinitiv und dem ohne "zu". Das "zu" ist in manchen Fällen optional, in manchen nicht.

Beim Verb *versuchen zu*  ist das *zu* nicht optional (außer in seiner transitiven Form, die an sich nur in der Bibel vorkommt - *jemanden versuchen*). Das *zu* vor dem *lösen* muss also auf jeden Fall hin.

Weiterhin sagt der Duden, dass der Infinitiv ein *zu* bekommen soll, wenn er im Satz *die Funktion des Subjekts* übernimmt. Hier kann man sich wahrscheinlich streiten, ob das in deinem Beispiel so ist - Für mich ist es so, denn man kann den Satz (holprig) zu

> Der Versuch,... zu.... ist mir ein Anliegen

umbauen. Damit gehört für mich das zweite *zu* auch in den Satz. Damit:

> Es wäre mir ein Anliegen, zu versuchen, den Fall alleine zu lösen.

(Hört sich eigentlich gar nicht so schlimm an?)

Wenn du unbedingt die beiden Infinitive beieinander stehen haben willst (was sich nun wirklich alles andere als elegant anhört), gelten natürlich dieselben Regeln:

> Es wäre mir ein Anliegen, den Fall alleine zu lösen zu versuchen.

Comment: Dass die letzte Variante klargeht, ist mir schon bewusst; ich möchte wissen, wie es um den Doppelinfinitiv steht.

Comment: @TanzWalzer Das ist doch ein doppelter infinitiv? Nur nicht beieinander. Ergänzt

Comment: Um die Eleganz geht's mir da gar nicht, lediglich darum, was möglich und was nicht. Danke.